# Convert a hex string in ASCII to the same hex values using Perl

Tags: string, perl, hex, ascii

I have a hexadecimal value as an ASCII string in Perl:

`42dc3f74212c4e74bab2` <-- This is a string, but this is also the actual hexadecimal value I need

I need to convert that to hex, and by converting I mean \x42\xdc\x3f, etc.

`$auth_key = pack("h*", $key);` #It kind of works, but it gives me a low nibble, so I end up with `24 cd f3`, etc.

How can I convert this string into hexadecimal of the same values!

I'm trying to feed this into a [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) socket if that helps.

Comment: BTW: $key = "\x42\xdc\x3f\x74\x21\x2c\x4e\x74\xba\xb2"; works just fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pack 'H*', $key`.

From `perldoc -fpack`:

```
h  A hex string (low nybble first).
H  A hex string (high nybble first).
```

Here is some output from the shell:

```
$perl -E'print pack "H*","42dc3f74212c4e74bab2"' | hd
00000000  42 dc 3f 74 21 2c 4e 74  ba b2                    |B.?t!,Nt..|
0000000a
```

Comment: This is how its suppose to look

42dc 3f74 212c  .j..`.....B.?t!,
        0x0030:  4e74 bab2                                Nt..

Thats with the $key manually set as in my comment above.

with h* I get 

24cd f347 12c2  .j..`.....$..G..
        0x0030:  e447 ab2b                                .G.+


and with H* I get

0400 14e5 ef37  5j...].........7
        0x0030:  3f31 5b2b 9264                           ?1[+.d

Comment: Yes, I tried H*, but I get 0400 14e5 ef37 3f31 5b2b 9264

#convert ascii back to hex
my $auth_key = pack("H*", $key);

Comment: @GlenBizeau Actually, it is the same. Unless you are dealing with interpolation.

Comment: `"` and `'` should act the same unless you're dealing with interpolation, *Edit:* @TLP was faster.

Comment: `#create the HMAC_SHA1 encryption 
my $hmac_sha1 = hmac_sha1_hex($data, $ascii);

#Grab the first 20 characters
my $key = substr($hmac_sha1, 0, 20);

#convert ascii back to hex
my $auth_key = pack('H*', $key);`

Comment: Either you didn't have `pack "H*"` (e.g. due to a miscontructed shell command), or you also changed something else at the same time.

Comment: @GlenBizeau If you change it back to `"`, does it stop working? I would be surprised if it did.

Comment: @TLP I changed it back and it works both ways. This is strange, I've been doing perl for about 20 years, love it. This is my first time playing with PACK and UNPACK though, never did any low level network stuff before. I could have swore it was only the " that I changed, but changing it back and it still works, so I don't know anymore. Was staring at that for hours wondering why it didn't work. I knew it should, especially when h* gave me the low nibble, so H* should have done it the proper way, but alas... We'll never know now :)  Thanks to both of you for the insight, more eyes sometimes.

Comment: Please note that on little endian architectures `perl -e 'print pack "H*","42dc3f74"' | hd` may produce `0000000 dc42 743f` instead, but this is caused by the little endian 16bit output of `hd`. The result of `pack` however is correct and as expected. Use `hd -t xc` for more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $str = "42dc3f74212c4e74bab2";
$str =~ s/(..)/chr(hex($1))/eg;  #hex() -> convert hex string to decimal number, chr() -> convert decimal number to a character(string).
say $str;

say (pack "H*","42dc3f74212c4e74bab2");

--output:--
B??t!,Nt??
B??t!,Nt??
```

Round trip with hexdump:

```
$ perl -E'print "42dc3f74212c4e74bab2" =~ s/(..)/chr(hex($1))/erg' | hexdump -C
00000000  42 dc 3f 74 21 2c 4e 74  ba b2                    |B.?t!,Nt..|
0000000a
```

pack()/unpack() are very efficient though, so they should be preferred.